# Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0 doesn't work behind proxy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The issue:

Help viewer is not able to fetch help catalog or to download picked items due to the proxy authentication error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This happens because because the Help Content Manager and BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) cannot fetch help data from Microsoft servers. Both Help Content Manager and BITS don't use default proxy credentials when connecting to Microsoft servers.

Fix:

Locate help viewer configuration at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.0\HlpViewer.exe.config
```

Edit the configuration file and add following to the configuration section:

```
<system.net>    
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >    
    </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

Now, in the same folder, create configuration for content manager:

```
HlpCtntMgr.exe.config
```

and add the same proxy settings to the configuration section.

Open registry editor and locate following node:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\BITS\
```

Make sure UseLMCompat value is present and it's set to 0. If the value is missing create it as a DWORD value.

Close the registry editor and restart Background Intelligent Transfer Service.

Comment: Trap for young players:  I overlooked the last line of Peter's answer and forgot to restart the BITS service.  Without that step I could see the list of documentation but I would get the proxy error when I clicked the Update button to download anything.  Restarting the BITS service was the step I needed to get the downloads working.

Comment: I've carefully followed the steps but it's not working for me. It could be related to my system using a "Dialup" VPN connection?
My HlpViewer.exe.config looks like (sorry, I couldn't get it to format the XML as code for this post):
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.net>    
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >    
    </defaultProxy> 
  </system.net>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: I've also confirmed that my default credentials are working via VS2010 and IE9. Any suggestions what I can do to get HelpViewer2.0 working?

Comment: The nearest I got to getting it working (it's still not working) was by using the following method to open the Network Login dialog box. From the start-screen in VS2012, click New Project, click Online, click "Please click here to enter your credentials".

Comment: Worked for me. Note, you may have other versions of help viewer installed. I had to edit the config files in the v2.2 directory.

Comment: On Windows 10 you also need to enable Windows Firewall service.